# Android radio streaming

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I have a problem with online radio streaming on Android (2.1). I'm using MediaPlayer like that:

```
player.setDataSource(mStationUrl);
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
player.prepareAsync();
```

The problem is that after run this code I can hear a second of the stream, then streaming is breaking for a few seconds, and next it runs again - this time properly.

So - how can I avoid this silent gap, or maybe I'm doing something wrong with player preparation?

I've done this with a few streams - always with the same results.

Comment: Think about buffering before playing.